# Ansible regex replace in variable to cisco interface names

Tags: ansible, network-programming

I'm currently working with a script to create interface descriptions based on CDP neighbor info, but it's placing the full names e.g., `GigabitEthernet1/1/1`, `HundredGigabitEthernet1/1/1`.

My regex is weak, but I would like to do a regex replace to keep only the first 3 chars of the interface name.

I think a pattern like `(dredGigatbitEthernet|abitEthernet|ntyGigabitEthernet|etc)` should work, but not sure how to put that into the playbook line below to modify the port value

```yaml
nxos_config:
  lines:
  - description {{ item.value[0].port }} ON {{ item.value[0].host }}
```

E.g, I am looking for `GigabitEthernet1/1/1` to end up as `Gig1/1/1`

Here is an example of input data:

```json
{ 
  "FastEthernet1/1/1": [{
    "host": "hostname", 
    "port": "Port 1"  
  }] 
}
```

Final play to make it correct using ansible net neighbors as the source

```
Thank you - I updated my play, adjusted for ansible net neighbors

- name: Set Interface description based on CDP/LLDP discovery
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.net_neighbors }}"
    - debug:
        msg: >- 
          description
          {{
            item[0].port 
            | regex_search('(.{3}).*([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)', '\1', '\2') 
            | join 
          }}
          ON {{ item.value[0].host }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.net_neighbors | dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Not totally clear what your output should be? `GigabitEthernet1/1/1` should then end in the 3 first char as `Gig` or should it be `1/1/1`? Or `1/1`?

Comment: Sorry, looking for GigabitEthernet1/1/1 to be Gig1/1/1

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want the three first characters along with the last 3 digits separated by a slash, then the regex `(.{3}).*([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)` should give you two capturing groups containing those two requirements.

In Ansible, you can use [`regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) to extract those groups, then join them back, with the help on the [`join` Jinja filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >- 
          description
          {{
            item.key 
            | regex_search('(.{3}).*([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)', '\1', '\2') 
            | join 
          }}
          ON {{ item.value[0].host }}"
      loop: "{{ interfaces | dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
      vars:
        interfaces:
          GigabitEthernet1/1/1:
            - port: Port 1 
              host: example.org
          HundredGigabitEthernet1/1/1:
            - port: Port 2
              host: example.com
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth0) => 
  msg: description Gig1/1/1 ON example.org"
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth1) => 
  msg: description Hun1/1/1 ON example.com"
```

Comment: So, that looked like it would work, but unfortunately it isn't working with live data from ansible_net_neighbors dictionary.  

From debug this is the net neighbors dictionary

"msg": {
        "FastEthernet1/1/1": [
            {
                "host": "hostname",
                "port": "Port 1"
            }
        ],
    }
}

Comment: This is because the data you claimed to be in `item.value[0].port` or actually in `item.key`.

Comment: Updated your question and the answer @ntwrkguy

Comment: Thank you - I updated my play -